# Is it possible to create a calendar which has week of 8 days and change language?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to do a calendar with flutter&dart and i want to create my own style of date time picker . How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code to everything in Flutter is available.  Take a look at how the existing Date/Time picker works, and copy the code and modify it.  Most of it will likely be the same.